# What is angular accelerating light?

Tags: optics, visible-light

[As described in this article](http://phys.org/news/2015-04-angular.html)

> "Our angular accelerating fields rely on combinations of orbital
>   angular momentum - so-called twisted light," says Forbes. Light
>   carrying orbital angular momentum is created by twisting the
>   wave-front of light into a helical shape, forming a spiral. Usually
>   this twist in the light's wave-front is smooth, like a spiral
>   staircase with regular steps. "Our novelty was to realise that by
>   twisting the helicity of these beams in a non-linear fashion, the
>   result would be a propagation dependent angular velocity," he
>   explains. In other words, the light spins at a non-constant speed,
>   resulting in angular acceleration.

Comment: I read through the article you link, and it isn't %100 clear to me either.  What I think they are talking about is: Certain spatial modes of monochromatic light have angular momentum, and they have found combinations of these modes which have changing angular momentum (i.e. angular acceleration) as they propagate.

Comment: They spin the light clockwise and counter-clockwise to make Internet faster, actually trying to. Maybe this is abut that